# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.db4o.Db4oEmbedded

Tags: android

I have added the jar to the libs folder and included it in the gradle.build file.  I have used libraries before in Android Studio without any issue, however, when I attempt to run this on the emulator, I get the error below.  I'm just wondering if I'm missing something or if there is something I could do to solve this issue.

```
09-20 21:51:53.144    1184-1184/com.kd.pokertracker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.db4o.Db4oEmbedded
    at com.kd.pokertracker.Services.DBService.openDb(DBService.java:27)
    at com.kd.pokertracker.Activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:62)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good jar(all classes exists in your jar) then try these steps:

1.clear your project.

2.put your jar into lib in place of libs folder.

3.In java build path make this jar on top.

[image]